# Save Response to Server When Network Connection goes OFF

Tags: android, firebase, internet-connection

I have two apps

> Client App

and

> Server App

in android

> What i want

To check in my server app that weather client app has internet connection or not.

> What i have done

I had read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547503/how-to-make-user-presence-mechanism-using-firebase/49547545#49547545)

I have used BroadcastReciever to Listen weather internet is available or not. All is well. When internet connection goes right , i am saving value **online to Firebase "true"**

> But

When internet connection goes off ,

i am using **Firebase onDisconnect() method to  save ServerValue.TIMESTAMP**

It works sometime in two minute but sometime it doesn't update firebase and value remains true.

Note what i want when client app is connected ,on firebase it should save true and when it is not connected it should save false . Though in my server app i will retreive those values to show to client is online or offline

is there any other technique to do such a scenario in android ?

What do you suggest any improvement in my current scenario. ?

Help will highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check Frank van Puffelen's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547545/5246885).

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for response but i have read that answer 5 times but didn't get. will you please lemme know somthing according to my scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

leave this **onDisconnect()**, write an API that will do nothing but will just ping the server after a fixed time continuously, let's say after each 2 seconds the API will be called(through service), so in case the net is disconnected or the cell phone is even off, since API will not respond to the server, here you will write a code in case app did't ping to the server after 2 seconds(or you can say after 5 seconds), the response(online status) should be **FALSE** automatically!

so in case the app is again connected to internet, since the service is running so service will update your false into **TRUE** again
that's too simple!

i think this is your required function!