# write firebase data when user is not connected to internet

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to update Firebase database when user is not connected to internet. It is like you are in the app and you close the internet connection now you close the application. So I am using `LifeCycleObserver` to detect whether the app is in foreground or in background. I want to set user status offline when onStop called in my Application class. When the internet connection is ON its working perfectly.

I have tried OnDisconnect().setValue(-) but its not working. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
userDatabase.child(AppConstants.USER_IS_ONLINE).onDisconnect().setValue(status,object :  DatabaseReference.CompletionListener{
            override fun onComplete(p0: DatabaseError?, p1: DatabaseReference) {
                Log.d("Success","YES")
            }

        })
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: When are you calling `onDisconnect()`? Keep in mind, you must call this when the user **is** connected to the server, otherwise the client has no way to send that instruction to the server.

Comment: I am calling onDisconnect() when the app is in foreground & in background both time. When my internet connection is on everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Frank van Puffelen  and Alex Mamo. I solved that problem. Thanks again to Frank van Puffelen your this point "you must call this when the user is connected to the server" clicked my mind. now its working perfectly. OnDisconnect called when our app is connected to server. The next problem i faced how to get back online the user when i got internet back for that i used job schedule. Now its working fine thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update firebase database when user is not connected to internet.

There is no way you can do this. Since there is no internet connection between user's device and Firebase servers, you cannot update anything. The internet connection is mandatory in order to reach Firebase back-end.

There are two ways the user can get disconnected from the Firebase database. For that, please see Frank van Puffelen's answer from the following post:

- [How to make user presence mechanism using Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547503/how-to-make-user-presence-mechanism-using-firebase)

Comment: In above post he mentioned "In the case of a clean disconnect, your onDisconnect handlers will immediately fire and thus your database will immediately be updated." but i am using onDisconnect(). still its not working ??

Comment: Yes, in case of a clean disconnect the onDisconnect handlers will fire. If the handlers won't fire, it means that you have not a clean disconnect, right?